# How to concatenate the percentage of a row in a single value?

Tags: r, dataframe, concatenation, row, percentage

I would like to concatenate the percentage of that value across the single row. Let say I have:

```
dat<-data.frame(x1=c(1), x2=c(4), x3=c(5), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

I would like to have a concatenate value in the `dat$concat` column like this: [10,40,50] (each value is the percentage now)

I previously asked how I can concatenate, and the command works pretty well:

```
dat$conc <- paste0("[",apply(dat,1,paste,collapse=","),"]")
```

How can I do it?

Comment: How about you accept answers to your previous questions before asking new ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we're assuming that 5 stands for 50%, then it's as easy as replacing dat with dat*.1, Like this:

```
dat <- data.frame(x1=c(1), x2=c(4), x3=c(5), stringsAsFactors = FALSE) 

dat$conc <- paste0("[",apply(dat*.1,1,paste,collapse=","),"]")

  x1 x2 x3          conc
1  1  4  5 [0.1,0.4,0.5]
```

But I do want to note that if 5 is meant to signify 5%, not 50%, then you would want to replace dat with dat/100, like this:

```
dat <- data.frame(x1=c(1), x2=c(4), x3=c(5), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

dat$conc <- paste0("[",apply(dat/100,1,paste,collapse=","),"]")

  x1 x2 x3             conc
1  1  4  5 [0.01,0.04,0.05]
```

**EDIT:**

To get the percentage of each value relative to its row (i.e. value/rowSums(x)), try this:

```
dat <- data.frame(x1=c(7),x2=c(4),x3=c(5),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

dat$conc <- paste0("[",apply(dat/rowSums(dat),1,paste,collapse=","),"]")
```

Output:

```
  x1 x2 x3                 conc
1  7  4  5 [0.4375,0.25,0.3125]
```

Comment: My bad: my example is clearly misleading. I was wondering how to do it if I have:
>dat<-data.frame(x1=c(7), x2=c(4), x3=c(5), stringsAsFactors = FALSE) 
So to get: [0.4375,0.25,0.3125]

Comment: @MikeJJ - Okay, I can adjust this, but how are those percentages being calculated, like 0.4375?

Comment: the percentage is for each row. 0.4375=7/(7+3+5)

Comment: @MikeJJ - Oh, okay. I've edited my solution to include that too then.

Comment: Thanks! Solved! I was doing a really stupid and embarrassing error! Thanks man!

Comment: @MikeJJ - No problem. Glad it was helpful.